# How to translate zoo blog component in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using 'zooblog of 2.5.14' in a site of joomla 2.5.1 where 'falang' language translator has been used.Can you tell me is it possible to translate zoo blog with 'ZOOlingual' in my site where I am using 'falang' language translator without any problem.I have got to know that with 'joomfish' it is possible but I don't know with 'falang'.
Please answere me so that I can translate zoo blog from spanish to english.

Comment: I have not got any answere.Is there any fault from me?

Answer (score 0):

All Joomla 2.5 extensions must comply with the multi-language standards.

Everything can be multi-language: menu items, content items, content modules, with other words, everything except the home menu  item that is unique and cannot be translated into several languages.

Here is a video tutorial I've made some years ago, watch and learn :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2enpEbmFXXA